# jack audio to generate a virtual sound card and input in it

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, jack

I receive 4 channel input via network in jack. and like to route this to a program which is not a jack client. in the program setting one can choose a sound card to read from. 
so to route audio from jack to this program I need an intermediate sound card.
I feel that this must be possible, isn't it?